# AWS amplify custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-amplify

can someone help me with this problem. I believe I am using the correct DNS record; ANAME(Alias record) for this but it is not working. I am using a third party domain name management instead of using the inhouse DNS 53 from AWS. I created a react application using amplify from aws but I am not able to point a record from my DNS. I have successfully added the DNS record(as you can see in the photo) but when I go to the record site it gives me the error below.

Thank you!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQpYu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Jrq.png)

Comment: are you able to access amplify link ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 yes I was able to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow some steps to achieve this :

1. Once you set up AWS Amplify
2. For Host, enter only the subdomain. For example, if your subdomain is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), enter www for Host.
3. For Points to, look at your DNS records in the Amplify Console and then enter the value. If the Amplify Console displays the domain for your app as xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net, enter xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net for Points to.

I think one correction you have to do is instead of amplify endpoint you have to get cloudfront endpoint as per step 3.

More details can find here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html

Comment: If this answer help don't forgot upvote answer.